# failing using def and input together

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

I'm a newbie to programming and trying to learn it with edx/microsoft.

I'm failing at this task somehow I don't understand it.

> Define yell_this() and call with variable argument
>
> ```
> define variable   words_to_yell   as a string gathered from user  input()
> Call  yell_this()  with   words_to_yell  as argument
> get user input() for the string words_to_yell
> ```

I'm using python 3 on an azure jupyter notebook on linux

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you pointed to the resource you are learning from. A link would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer to the best of my understanding of this question

Step 1.

> define variable   words_to_yell   as a string gathered from user  input()

In python you can define a variable like this:

```
words_to_yell = input('Please provide a word to yell: ')
```

This will define a variable containing whatever the user passed in

Step 2.

> Call  yell_this()  with   words_to_yell  as argument
>   Assuming you have this function defined, you can call it like this

```
yell_this(words_to_yell)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have solved my issue  i didn't define words_to_yell before !

Answer (score 0):

#define the function and ask for user input

```
def words_to_yell():
    words_to_yell = input("Please type words to yell:")
    print(words_to_yell.upper() + "!!!")
```

#call the function like this:

```
words_to_yell()
```